# CoordinatorLayout com RecyclerView em outro fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Tenho um `Fragment` com um `CoordinatorLayout` e um `FrameLayout` pra popular com outros Fragments. Um desses Fragments contem um `RecyclerView`.

Gostaria de saber como faço pra fazer o `RecyclerView` funcionar com o `CoordinatorLayout` sendo que cada um está em um arquivo. Ja tentei colocar um `NestedScrollView` como pai do `Fragment` que tem o `RecyclerView`, mas quando faço isso o `onBindViewHolder` do adapter do `RecyclerView` é chamado pra todos os elementos e aí não consigo fazer busca paginada pra preencher o `RecyclerView`.

Código do Fragment principal que contém o CoordinatorLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorTab"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_restaurant"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Código do Fragment que tem o RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/background"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Dessa forma o *scroll* até funciona porém o `onBindViewHolder` é chamado pra todos os itens da lista, inclusive para os que não estão sendo exibidos. Se eu coloco um `LinearLayout` ao invés do `NestedScrollView`, o `onBindViewHolder` funciona da maneira correta mas o comportamento de *scroll* `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` com o `CoordinatorLayout` não funciona.

Comment: Já tentou colocar o NestedScrollView como pai do `container_restaurant`?